# Can one use VMWare vCloud API in its own datacenter

Tags: powershell, cloud, vmware, powercli

Currently we're building a small datacenter. For the Infrastructure-as-a-Service part I'm planning to use VMWare vSphere. I know VMWare is pushing its vCloud API so my question is: how can I install and use this API within my own datacenter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going to use vSphere I strongly advise you to examine [PowerCLI](http://communities.vmware.com/community/vmtn/vsphere/automationtools/powercli). PowerCLI is snapin to Powershell. With PowerCLI you have wonders of Powershell and tools which you can use to automate / manage almost any aspect of vSphere.

vCloud API is currently at beta and it's targeted to vCloud Service Director. It's currently private beta.

Comment: To close my question, I've implemented all the communication using PowerCLI. Documentations suks, but still usable. Had to learn a lot with reflector but in the end - I have working product

Answer (score 0):

Right now VMware is expecting this to be implemented by the service providers themselves. For example BlueLock, Terramark and Hosting.com have implementations provided by the companies' implementations of vCloud Express.